# Python lambda sorted function how to code it properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, reverse

I have a list of all countries in the world with its population e.g.

```
Countries = [("argentina", 124854), ("brazil",568854)]
```

The first value is a `string=country` the second is `integer = population`

The task is sort the list by it second value by using reverse true when sorted, I have managed to do it by the string first value country in analphabetic order ASC and DESC but I don't know how to write the code to sort by population in from the largest to smallest population?

```
pop lambda country:country[1]
countries.sort(key=pop, reverse=True)
Countries
```

This code doesn't work as expected.

Comment: "This code doesn't work as expected." What happens instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Countries = [("argentina", 124854), ("brazil",568854)]

print(sorted(Countries, key=lambda k: k[1], reverse=True))
```

Prints:

```
[('brazil', 568854), ('argentina', 124854)]
```

---

Or:

```
print(sorted(Countries, key=lambda k: -k[1]))
```